# Best way to persist JPA entities in Play framework

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, persistence, playframework

I'm new to JPA, let alone JPA in Play, so I'm wondering what is the best way to save my objects with a `@ManyToOne` relationship to multiple classes.

The UserJump class is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
public class UserJump extends Model{
    @ManyToOne
    public User user;
    @ManyToOne
    public JumpSession jumpSession;
    public String parachuteUID;
    public String notes;
    public int status;
```

}

The relationship to UserJump is defined from inside JumpSession by :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="jumpSession")
public List<UserJump> userJumps;
```

Likewise in the User class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
public List<UserJump> userJumps;
```

Here's how I'm saving things right now:

```
JumpSession jumpSession = new JumpSession();
//...Code here to fill in jumpSession...
jumpSession.save();

UserJump userJump;
for(String jumperUID : jumpers)
{
    userJump = new UserJump();
    userJump.jumpSession = jumpSession;
    userJump.user = User.findById(jumperUID);
    userJump.status = 1;
    userJump.save();
}
```

It seems to me that there should be a way to save those UserJump objects in a List called userJumps and then do `jumpSession.userJumps = userJumps`, then `jumpSession.save()` and it should persist all the UserJump objects.  Is there a way to do this?  And which way is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can cascade save from `JumpSession` to `UserJump` by setting an appropriate cascading option:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="jumpSession", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) 
public List<UserJump> userJumps;
```

Also, I don't think it's a good idea to make relationship from `UserJump` to `User` bidirectional. In the case of `JumpSession` it's fine since `UserJump`s can be treated as parts of `JumpSession` (for example, they are saved along with the `JumpSession`). But in the case of `User` it doesn't make sense, so that I recommend you to remove `userJumps` field from `User`. When you need `UserJump` for particular `User`, make an explicit query instead.

More on the last point. I think that number of `UserJump`s per `JumpSession` is likely to be bounded, whereas number of `UserJump`s per `User` is potentially unbounded. It means that `UserJump`s of `User` should be displayed with some kind of pagination, that makes `userJumps` field useless.

So, considering complications introduced by to-many relationships ([Deterring “ToMany” Relationships in JPA models](http://java.dzone.com/articles/deterring-%E2%80%9Ctomany%E2%80%9D?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20javalobby/frontpage%20%28Javalobby%20/%20Java%20Zone%29), [Hibernate mapped collections performance problems](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/hibernate-mapped-collections.html) 
) I think it would be better to remove this field altogether.

Comment: Well, it was originally a `@ManyToMany` relationship between User and JumpSession, but I needed to have more columns in the joining table.  A User will be constantly viewing all the Jump Sessions they belong to, and that relationship is maintained by UserJump (which stores data about the jump).  Why would it be bad to have the relationship bidirectional?  The user has as much relation to the UserJump as the JumpSession.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain.  So, even if there is a one to many relationship between two entities, if the ratio of one to the other is unbounded, it shouldn't be mapped as such?  I'm guessing that's a general rule, not one applicable only here.

Comment: @Indigenuity: Basically yes, though some OO purists may disagree. The point is that if having a mapped relationship would be useless for your code, you can omit it.